# Window.createPopup equivalent for otherthan IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to get window.createpopup like tooltip for browsers like Firefox, chrome and safari?

Can we use div?

In my scenario it should display as tooltip.

If we use how to change below code to other browsers?

```
 var oPopupBody = oPopup.document.body;
    var sBody = "<span style='background-color:#ffffc4;border:2px solid black;height:100%;width:100%;'>";
    if (sLabel) {
        sBody += "<span style='font:10pt arial;font-weight:bold;padding-left:2px;text-align:center;width:100%;'>" + sLabel + "</span>";
    }
    sBody += "</span>";
    oPopupBody.innerHTML = sBody;
    oLink.title = '';
    oPopup.show(oLink.offsetWidth, -10, iW, iH, oLink);
    oLink.title = sLabel;
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use jquery for this, something along these lines:

```
$(element).hover(
  function(){
    $(this).find(child-element).show();
  },
  function(){
    $(this).find(child-element).hide();
  }
);
```

Something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/AShzJ/